# passing Arguments with URL

Tags: objective-c

```
-(void)getWord:(NSString*)upperCaseString :(NSString *)combinedString :(NSString *)wordIndex
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://quicklanguages.com/materiales/quicklanguages/audios/%@/%@-%@.mp3",@"upperCaseString", @"combinedString", @"wordIndex" ];
    //  [tweetSheet setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", 
    [[_items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"redirect_url"]]];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:nil]; 
    // Now we are assigning it in an instance variable thus ARC will not deallocate it.
    [audioPlayer play];
}
```

I make a method and passing three arguments , Now can can set these arguments with this URL .....

Comment: Please update your question with the code as text in addition to the picture.

Comment: -(void)getWord:(NSString*)upperCaseString :(NSString *)combinedString :(NSString *)wordIndex
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://quicklanguages.com/materiales/quicklanguages/audios/%@/%@-%@.mp3",@"upperCaseString", @"combinedString", @"wordIndex" ];}

Comment: Don't post code in comments. Update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to do it is this:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://bla.bla/bla/%@/%@-%@.mp3", @"upperCaseString", @"combinedString", @"wordIndex"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

**Edit:**

The final code will look like this:

```
-(void)getWord:(NSString*)upperCaseString :(NSString *)combinedString :(NSString *)wordIndex
{
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://quicklanguages.com/materiales/quicklanguages/audios/%@/%@-%@.mp3",@"upperCaseString", @"combinedString", @"wordIndex"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    //  [tweetSheet setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", 
    [[_items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"redirect_url"]]];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:nil]; 
    // Now we are assigning it in an instance variable thus ARC will not deallocate it.
    [audioPlayer play];
}
```

Comment: not working , using Same Syntax But still error "Too many arguments to method call, expected 1, have 4"

Comment: The code you posted doesn't show the change I suggested

Comment: Thanks , Now it works..